# ggplot complains about applying code to the data

Tags: r

I have strange problem which I can't solve on my own.

That's how my original data looks like:

```
> dput(df[1:25])
structure(c(2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1), .Names = c("AT1G01050", "AT1G01090", 
"AT1G01320", "AT1G01470", "AT1G01560", "AT1G02150", "AT1G02560", 
"AT1G02780", "AT1G02920", "AT1G03090", "AT1G03130", "AT1G03220", 
"AT1G03230", "AT1G03330", "AT1G03630", "AT1G03680", "AT1G03870", 
"AT1G04080", "AT1G04170", "AT1G04270", "AT1G04410", "AT1G04480", 
"AT1G04690", "AT1G04710", "AT1G04810"))
```

I try to create a ggplot using function below:

```
dat <- as.data.frame(df[1:25]))
dat$factor <-1
ggplot(dat,aes(x=factor,fill=factor(dat))) +
  geom_bar(binwidth=5) +
  coord_flip()
```

and as a result I got this error:

```
Error in sort.list(y) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'
Have you called 'sort' on a list?
```

but...

when I tried to use same code on the example data which has exactly the same (at least in my opinion) structure it worked fine yesterday but right now it does not... Both data sets are called `Named numeric`:

```
> dput(data)
structure(c(2, 8, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 7, 6, 4, 1), .Names = c("Mark", 
"Greg", "Sonya", "Monica", "Tiana", "Arra", "Armin", "Hera", 
"Cyrus", "Pier", "Tina", "Hector", "Markus"))
```

Comment: maybe you should try changing the names of the data or try this `fill=factor(factor)`

Comment: you are trying to use factor function on data.frame. you can use factor only on vector `?factor` will help you on this

Answer (score -1):

I used your example data but works fine for both. I believe that's what you are looking for:

```
dat <- as.data.frame(data)
dat$factor <-1
ggplot(dat,aes(x=as.numeric(factor),fill=factor(dat[,1]))) + geom_bar(binwidth=5) + coord_flip()
```

[image: Example data]

Comment: `ggplot` is designed tu use names of data, you do not want to do it that way